# How to get picture buffer data in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to pass bitmap from ffmpeg to android.
It already works but it's displaying picture right on surface passed from java to native code.
How can i get frame buffer bitmap data to pass it to java?

I've tried to save out_frame buffer data:

```
unsigned char bmpFileHeader[14] = {'B', 'M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 54, 0,0,0};
unsigned char bmpInfoHeader[40] = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0, 24,0};
unsigned char bmpPad[3] = {0, 0, 0};

void saveBuffer(int fileIndex, int width, int height, unsigned char *buffer, int buffer_size) {

    unsigned char filename[1024];
    sprintf(filename, "/storage/sdcard0/3d_player_%d.bmp", fileIndex);

    LOGI(10, "saving ffmpeg bitmap file: %d to %s", fileIndex, filename);

    FILE *bitmapFile = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!bitmapFile) {
        LOGE(10, "failed to create ffmpeg bitmap file");
        return;
    }

    unsigned char filesize = 54 + 3 * width * height; // 3 = (r,g,b)

    bmpFileHeader[2] = (unsigned char)(filesize);
    bmpFileHeader[3] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 8);
    bmpFileHeader[4] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 16);
    bmpFileHeader[5] = (unsigned char)(filesize >> 24);

    bmpInfoHeader[4] = (unsigned char)(width);
    bmpInfoHeader[5] = (unsigned char)(width >> 8);
    bmpInfoHeader[6] = (unsigned char)(width >> 16);
    bmpInfoHeader[7] = (unsigned char)(width >> 24);
    bmpInfoHeader[8] = (unsigned char)(height);
    bmpInfoHeader[9] = (unsigned char)(height >> 8);
    bmpInfoHeader[10] = (unsigned char)(height >> 16);
    bmpInfoHeader[11] = (unsigned char)(height >> 24);

    fwrite(bmpFileHeader, 1, 14, bitmapFile);
    fwrite(bmpInfoHeader, 1, 40, bitmapFile);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<height; i++) {
        fwrite(buffer + width * (height - 1) * 3, 3, width, bitmapFile);
        fwrite(bmpPad, 1, (4-(width * 3) % 4) % 4, bitmapFile);
    }

    fflush(bitmapFile);
    fclose(bitmapFile);
}


    int player_decode_video(struct DecoderData * decoder_data, JNIEnv * env,
        struct PacketData *packet_data) {
    int got_frame_ptr;
    struct Player *player = decoder_data->player;
    int stream_no = decoder_data->stream_no;
    AVCodecContext * ctx = player->input_codec_ctxs[stream_no];
    AVFrame * frame = player->input_frames[stream_no];
    AVStream * stream = player->input_streams[stream_no];
    int interrupt_ret;
    int to_write;
    int err = 0;
    AVFrame *rgb_frame = player->rgb_frame;
    ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;
    ANativeWindow * window;

#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
    struct timespec timespec1, timespec2, diff;
#endif // MEASURE_TIME
    LOGI(10, "player_decode_video decoding");
    int frameFinished;

#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timespec1);
#endif // MEASURE_TIME
    int ret = avcodec_decode_video2(ctx, frame, &frameFinished,
            packet_data->packet);

#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timespec2);
    diff = timespec_diff(timespec1, timespec2);
    LOGI(3, "decode_video timediff: %d.%9ld", diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_nsec);
#endif // MEASURE_TIME

    if (ret < 0) {
        LOGE(1, "player_decode_video Fail decoding video %d\n", ret);
        return -ERROR_WHILE_DECODING_VIDEO;
    }
    if (!frameFinished) {
        LOGI(10, "player_decode_video Video frame not finished\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // saving in buffer converted video frame
    LOGI(7, "player_decode_video copy wait");

#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timespec1);
#endif // MEASURE_TIME

    pthread_mutex_lock(&player->mutex_queue);
    window = player->window;
    if (window == NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&player->mutex_queue);
        goto skip_frame;
    }
    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, ctx->width, ctx->height,
            WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888);
    if (ANativeWindow_lock(window, &buffer, NULL) != 0) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&player->mutex_queue);
        goto skip_frame;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&player->mutex_queue);

    int format = buffer.format;
    if (format < 0) {
        LOGE(1, "Could not get window format")
    }
    enum PixelFormat out_format;
    if (format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        out_format = PIX_FMT_RGBA;
        LOGI(6, "Format: WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888");
    } else if (format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBX_8888) {
        out_format = PIX_FMT_RGB0;
        LOGE(1, "Format: WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBX_8888 (not supported)");
    } else if (format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565) {
        out_format = PIX_FMT_RGB565;
        LOGE(1, "Format: WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565 (not supported)");
    } else {
        LOGE(1, "Unknown window format");
    }

    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) rgb_frame, buffer.bits, out_format,
            buffer.width, buffer.height);
    rgb_frame->data[0] = buffer.bits;
    if (format == WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        rgb_frame->linesize[0] = buffer.stride * 4;
    } else {
        LOGE(1, "Unknown window format");
    }
    LOGI(6,
            "Buffer: width: %d, height: %d, stride: %d",
            buffer.width, buffer.height, buffer.stride);
    int i = 0;

#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timespec2);
    diff = timespec_diff(timespec1, timespec2);
    LOGI(1,
            "lockPixels and fillimage timediff: %d.%9ld", diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_nsec);
#endif // MEASURE_TIME
#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &timespec1);
#endif // MEASURE_TIME
    LOGI(7, "player_decode_video copying...");
    AVFrame * out_frame;
    int rescale;
    if (ctx->width == buffer.width && ctx->height == buffer.height) {
        // This always should be true
        out_frame = rgb_frame;
        rescale = FALSE;
    } else {
        out_frame = player->tmp_frame2;
        rescale = TRUE;
    }

    if (ctx->pix_fmt == PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
        __I420ToARGB(frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0], frame->data[2],
                frame->linesize[2], frame->data[1], frame->linesize[1],
                out_frame->data[0], out_frame->linesize[0], ctx->width,
                ctx->height);
    } else if (ctx->pix_fmt == PIX_FMT_NV12) {
        __NV21ToARGB(frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0], frame->data[1],
                frame->linesize[1], out_frame->data[0], out_frame->linesize[0],
                ctx->width, ctx->height);
    } else {
        LOGI(3, "Using slow conversion: %d ", ctx->pix_fmt);
        struct SwsContext *sws_context = player->sws_context;
        sws_context = sws_getCachedContext(sws_context, ctx->width, ctx->height,
                ctx->pix_fmt, ctx->width, ctx->height, out_format,
                SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        player->sws_context = sws_context;
        if (sws_context == NULL) {
            LOGE(1, "could not initialize conversion context from: %d"
            ", to :%d\n", ctx->pix_fmt, out_format);
            // TODO some error
        }
        sws_scale(sws_context, (const uint8_t * const *) frame->data,
                frame->linesize, 0, ctx->height, out_frame->data,
                out_frame->linesize);
    }

    if (rescale) {
        // Never occurs
        __ARGBScale(out_frame->data[0], out_frame->linesize[0], ctx->width,
                ctx->height, rgb_frame->data[0], rgb_frame->linesize[0],
                buffer.width, buffer.height, __kFilterNone);
        out_frame = rgb_frame;
    }

    // TODO: (4ntoine) frame decoded and rescaled, ready to call callback with frame picture from buffer
    int bufferSize = buffer.width * buffer.height * 3; // 3 = (r,g,b);  

    static int bitmapCounter = 0;
    if (bitmapCounter < 10) {
        saveBuffer(bitmapCounter++, buffer.width, buffer.height, (unsigned char *)out_frame->data, bufferSize);
    }
```

but out_frame is empty and file has header and 0x00 bytes body.

**How to get picture buffer data in ffmpeg?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in short: you should take buffer from ANativeWindow_Buffer - buffer.bits. Pay attention buffer is (rgba) but BMP is usually (rgb) - 3 bytes. To save it as BMP one need to add BMP header and save lines with padding.